# multithreading with calling the same function

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I come up with this question that was asked to write a code in C++. So, I need to use the C++ synchronization primitives.

Q: Create a method (e.g. foo) which accept a integer as a argument and print on console. This method is accessed by multiple threads. If two or more threads call the method with same value then only one thread should allow to print the value other threads should wait. If values are different then all threads should allow to print the value.

My suggestion is using a global hashtable lets say, unordered_map(i, semaphore) map. So, when foo(i) is called, foo checks the hashtable. If i is not in the hashtable, we add map[i]=semaphore(0). When i printed, map[i].release() is called to allow other waiting threads with input i continue their print operation. On the other hand, if i is already in the hash, it means that other thread with the same input is running, so it should wait via map[i].aquire().

Hope you could help me to find a better solution or a corrected version of this proposal.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: @nosid I believe that using a global hashtable is not a robust approach and so there should be a better solution for that.

Comment: Is console output already synchronized? If not, you'd have to handle that as well. Getting back to the original question, the method only needs to keep track of the most recent value output, and the other threads aren't made to wait (except for a mutex or semaphore when accessing / updating that most recent value output), their output requests are just ignored if a match to the last value output.

Comment: @rcgldr could you give a pseudo code about your approach?Unfortunately I do not fully understand how you tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Example Using Windows functions and a static global mutex.

```
static HANDLE hMutex;    // initialized elsewhere
// ...

void DisplayInt(int value)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex);
    // ... check value and display message
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
}
```

Comment: A more complicated option would be to create yet another thread that displays values passed to it via some form of inter thread messaging. Again it would avoid displaying a value that is the same as the previous displayed value.